# Transforming api json responses for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm ending up having to do hacks to convert `'true'` to just `true` and it's creating code smell.

Is there a library like https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal that allows me to transform my response into the types I need?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to always convert the string `'true'` to the boolean `true`. Can you modify the API to return the correct type? the JSON format does support `true` and `false`.

Comment: It's not just that I want to be able to transform values on child arrays.  Strings like `,true,true` to `[null,true,true]` for an AngularJS app

Comment: If you're getting strings like `',true,true'` instead of proper JSON arrays then that's a problem with the API :(

Comment: @david Ahhh I shall change that then.  It's stored in a MySQL database  and not sure of best way to store a simple array.

Comment: If you don't need to do queries on the elements of the array and will always return it whole then you could just convert it to a JSON string and chuck it in an nvarchar

Comment: @david I changed my schema to better reflect what I wanted since I happen to be dealing with days of the week which are constant (unless the earth slows down or speeds up). I'm hesitant to do json in my db unless it's FabricJS canvas or something.  I need to be able to pull analytics without using `LIKE`. Submit an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this it's almost always better to fix the API to return data in a usable format rather than trying to post-process the result on the client.

In your case there are several routes you could take:

1. Store the list as a JSON string directly in the database.

   This means you don't have to do any processing on the server and can just return it 'as is'. However you lose the ability to do queries on the data directly and need to resort to things like `LIKE` and string operations.
2. Store the data relationally, and process it on the server to turn it into JSON

   Here you retain the ability to do queries on your data, but you may need to do several queries to get all the data you need and then connect it on the server. (eg. you would do one `SELECT` on the `user` table to get a user, and then you would need to do another `SELECT` on the `friends` table where the userid matches your first user. You would then need to merge these results to create your JSON.)  This is usually the best way to do it.
3. You can also turn the result into JSON directly inside the database engine using a user defined function. For example using https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_json#readme

   This is somewhat similar to 2, but it ties your stored procs to the JSON format.